# Recommendations for a PDF viewer with "web browser"-like navigation

Tags: linux, pdf, debian

Am looking for a PDF reader that can navigate PDF files like a web browser (IE, when I click a link that takes me to another part of the doc, I should be able to go back by pressing Ctrl+left arrow). I am using Debian.

Comment: Doesn't Adobe Reader already do that?

Comment: Am sure it does, but I should have specified that I was looking for FLOSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like [Foxit reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/index.php).

In Foxit, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to go to previous "view" (as they call it), and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for next one.

Comment: This is, however, not FLOSS — just freeware with a restrictive EULA and no source available (much like Adobe Reader).